# DD4T Cache Invalidation in-consistent behaviour

Tags: 2013-sp1, dd4t, cache, jms, apachemq

I have implemented JMS based cache invalidation mechanism using Apache MQ, application is MVC.NET 4.0 application, I found there is lot of inconsistent behavior while we try to invalidate the cache, both Tridion Object and DD4T cache are enabled.

Following is the observation

MVC.NET does not support JMS object messaging so a custom `TextJMSCacheChannelConnector` class needs to be used (https://github.com/dd4t/dd4t-cachechannel) to handle text messages at both deployer and website level

If we implement `TextJMSCacheChannelConnector` class Tridion Object Cache does not gets invalidated as `HandleMessage` method is not implemented in `TextJMSCacheChannelConnector` and `HandleMessage` method in `JMSCacheChannelConnector` class is not handling Text Message and throwing error "Message Type not supported"

If Default `JMSCacheChannelConnector` is used then Tridion object cache does get invalidated, however DD4T cache does not get invalidated because it uses `TextJMSCacheChannelConnector` and it is not capable of handling object messaging.

I think we might need to implement a `HandleMessage` method in `TextJMSCacheChannelConnector` to handle text based messages as well.

Regards,
Sameer

Comment: Interesting question, but I'm not sure what sort of answer you are looking for? The way I see it you sort of are answering your own question in your last sentence, so perhaps you are looking for a validation of that? Furthermore, if the question is clear, it will be a good fit for this site of course, but I think you might also want to report it as an issue on the DD4T GitHub repository (https://github.com/dd4t/dd4t-cachechannel/issues)

Comment: When you use Tridion’s content delivery API to retrieve dynamic content, resolve links, etc, you are well advised to use the built-in caching mechanism. Without it, every page request would result in dozens of queries on your broker database (or dozens of data files being opened, which is just as bad for performance). With caching, most requests can be handled completely from memory, which makes your site a lot faster. We used this https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.Caching.ApacheMQ it's works as awesome